# Get informations by CustomerId using MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, java-ee-6

I have 3 entities Customer, Data and Information. The relationship between the entities is oneToMany like this:

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
 ...
 @OneToMany
 private List<Data> datas;
 ...

public class Data implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataBase")
    private List<Information> informations;
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
..

public class Information implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne
    private Data dataBase;
...
```

Now i want that each customer logged in can see only its own informations.
I am thinking abt using JPQL named query.
So i write this method in the manged Bean of information

```
public List<Information> getInformations() {  
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)      context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String idCustomer = (String) session.getAttribute("idCustomer");
        Customer cust = customerBusinessLocal.findById(idCustomer);
        List<Data> datas=dataBusinessLocal.findByCustomer(cust);
        return InformationBusinessLocal.informations(datas);      
    }
```

But i got javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Comment: How about starting with a tutorial?

Comment: Do you know any usefull one?

Comment: I'm confident that any tutorial found using the appropriate keywords will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public List<Information`enter code here`> getInformations() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        String idCustomer = (String) session.getAttribute("idCustomer");
        System.out.println(idCustomer + " this is it");
        Customer cust = customerBusinessLocal.findById(idCustomer);
        List<Data> datas = dataBusinessLocal.findByCustomer(cust);
        for(Data d: datas)
         {           
             for(Information i: d.getInformations()){          
                 informations.add(i);
         } 
             } 
        return informations;
    }
```